# LINQ Operations on Lambda Grouping

Tags: linq, lambda, group-by

I'm stuck with a LINQ group by situation trying to solve it without using `foreach` statement, here is the escenary:

I have two generic collections `List<OrderHeader>` and `List<OrderDetail>`, both have a same field `TOTRGVS` that contains total amount from a order, and the number of order is the key named `NDORGV`.

Then I want to find "Orders that not have the same `TOTRGVS` in `OrderHeader` and `OrderDetail`", so I tried the following query:

```
 List<RGVCAFAC_ERRORES> diff = (from d in lstOrderDetail 
                               join c in lstOrderHeader on d.NDORGV equals c.NDORGV                                                     
                               group d by d.NDORGV into g
                               let difTOTOrderDetail = g.Select(p => p.TOTRGVS).Sum()
                               let difTOTOrderHeader = g.Key.????
                               let diffTOT = difTOTOrderHeader - difTOTOrderDetail
                               where diffTOT != 0
                               select new _ERRORS
                               {
                                   NDORGV = g.Key,
                                   IMPORT = diffTOT
                               }
  ).ToList();
```

in `difTOTOrderHeader` I don't know how to retrieve the `TOTRGVS` field from `OrderHeader`. I have tried using Key but can't get any field, just extensions for formatting methods.

Comment: If you think its hard to get this done without using a foreach loop, consider how much harder it will be to debug.  Go ahead and use a loop if that makes it easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might do the trick:

```
var dictDetails = lstOrderDetail
  .GroupBy(d => d.NDORGV)
  .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Sum(d => d.TOTRGVS));

var result = lstOrderHeader
  .Where(h => dictDetails[h.NDORGV] != h.TOTRGVS)
  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Except` function is normally used to determine differences in lists.

Comment: Excepts in Header or Detail? when already exists a group by X and X determines the "selected objects", also I forget tell that Detail can have more than one row thats the cause I use group sum!